# Proving two spaces are homeomorphic

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to show that in the Euclidean Topology (also called the usual topology), the product $\mathbb R^m \times \mathbb R^n \equiv \mathbb R^{m+n}$. That is, show a homeomorphism.

My difficulty lies is the determination of a function $f\colon \mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^m\to \mathbb{R}^{m+n}$.

Am I correct in assuming that an element in $\mathbb{R}^m\times\mathbb{R}^n$ looks like $[(a_1,b_1)\times\cdots\times (a_m,b_m)]\times[(c_1,d_1)\times\cdots\times (c_n,d_n)]$?

Comment: No, it looks like $((a_1, \ldots, a_m), (b_1, \ldots, b_n))$.

Comment: No. An element of the product looks like this: $(x,y)$ where $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $y\in\mathbb{R}^m$.

Comment: @Cloudscape you got $m,n$ reversed...

Comment: @uniquesolution: You confused $n$ and $m$. Or Chesso did.

Comment: depends on which line you read

Comment: You are right. He has both ways. I was reading the line starting with "My difficulty". You were reading the other. Doesn't matter, really.

Comment: Maybe you can start by showing the euclidean metric topology agrees with the product topology on $\mathbb R^n$. Then, it's just the associativity of the product.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proving Homeomorphisms (Topology)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1478687/proving-homeomorphisms-topology)

Comment: Yes. I it should be $\mathbb{R}^m\times \mathbb{R}^n$. So if an element looks like ((a_1,\ldots, a_m),(b_1,\ldots, b_n)), the function I need is $f((a_1,\ldots, a_m),(b_1,\ldots, b_n)) = (c_1,\ldots, c_{m+n})$? So to show $f^{-1}$ is continuous, I need to show $f^{-1}((c_1,\ldots, c_{m+n}))$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^m\times\mathbb{R}^n$. But is this clear since such a set of $m+n$ elements must be composed of a set if $m$ elements and a set of $n$ elements which is open in $\mathbb{R}^m\times\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: You basically reposted your first two questions as two new questions. Please don't do that, I'm voting for closing both as duplicates.

Comment: Your function value should be containing terms involving a_1,a_2,...,a_n and b_1,b_2,b_3,...,b_m@Chesso

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Consider the geometric picture of what $\Bbb{R}^m\times \Bbb{R}^n$ means . It means that pasting a copy of $\Bbb{R}^m$ at every point of $\Bbb{R}^n$. So I think you can tell the function now .